# Running Django tests without collect static

Tags: python, django, pytest

I am trying to run a test suite for django that uses inlinecss. inlinecss references a static file in the template as follows:

```py
{% load inlinecss %}
{% inlinecss "css/emails/base.css" %}
```

When running in Debug mode this works fine, when running in production (having run `collectstatic`) this also works fine.

However when running tests (without running collectstatic before) I get the following:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/project-name/staticfiles/css/emails/base.css'
```

This makes sense as django is looking for the file in STATIC_ROOT (`STATIC_ROOT = os.path.normpath(join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "staticfiles"))`)

I am wondering if there is a way to allow Django to access this file without having to run `collectstatic`? It would be ideal if I could add some settings to `test.py` so that it could collectstatic to a tmp directory or not require collectstatic at all (like when running in debug mode) but I have had no success trying this. I am using pytest to run tests.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this? I have the same problem and I'm not sure how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I used follow construction to collect static files to temporary folder during test. I am sure this solution might not be the most optimal for a large number of tests, but it should work well for individual test cases.

```
import tempfile
import shutil
from contextlib import contextmanager
from django.core.management import call_command
from django.test import TestCase, override_settings

@contextmanager
def static_files_context():
    static_root = tempfile.mkdtemp(prefix="test_static")
    with override_settings(STATIC_ROOT=static_root):
        try:
            call_command("collectstatic", "--noinput")
            yield
        finally:
            shutil.rmtree(static_root)

class YourTestCase(TestCase):

    @override_settings(STATIC_ROOT=None)
    def test_your_test_name(self):
        with static_files_context():
            # Your test code
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution provided by [Oleksandr Kozachenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22269033/oleksandr-kozachenko) converted to a pytest fixture.

```
import shutil
import tempfile

import pytest
from django.core.management import call_command


@pytest.fixture
def staticfiles(settings):
    static_root = tempfile.mkdtemp(prefix="test_static")
    settings.STATIC_ROO = static_root
    try:
        call_command("collectstatic", "--noinput")
        yield
    finally:
        shutil.rmtree(static_root)
```